# undefined reference to `main' c language

Tags: c

I tried compiling my code with:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu89 0-isupper.c -o 0-isuper
```

But its showing:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the source code:

```c
#include "main.h"

/**
*_isupper - checks for uppercase character
*_isupper - checks for uppercase character
*_isupper - checks for uppercase character
*@c: character to be checked
*Return: 1 if true, 0 if false
*/

int _isupper(int c)
{
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    {
        return (1);
    }
    else
    {
       return (0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I don't see  `main` function, so the linker is correct in complaining.

Comment: Who is supposed to call your `_isupper` function? Every program must have a `main` function that is the entry point at startup.

Comment: You have a `main.h` so perhaps function `main` is in another file which you don't tell the linker about.

Comment: are you trying to build an entire program or just a library? If you want a full program, the other comments are valid - you need a main() function. If just a library, you probably need to specify such in your build (gcc) command.

Comment: If you just want to compile but not link then add `-c`

Comment: Each C or C++ program must have main function which it the entry point of the program, like:
int main() {  /* your code */
return  0; }

linker tells you that there is no main function

Answer (score 0):

To successfully create a executable from C code, you need to implement the `main()` function. If you implemented `main()` elsewhere, then replace `-o 0-isuper` with `-c` flag so that it merely creates an object file. Subsequently, you can use `ld` to link `0-isuper.o` with some other object file that implemented `main()` to create an executable.